# Integrate Cricket Upcoming Matches from API Issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

I am trying to integrate cricket upcoming matches from API, but I don't know where I am going wrong.

I'm new to JSON please help me out fetch values from JSON (which in API), I have hidden my API key using *XXXX* variable,

I tried using alert it's not print anything:

Code:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({ 
type: 'GET', 
url: 'http://cricapi.com/api/cricket/?apikey=XXXX', 
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){ 
    $.each(this, function(key, value) {

            container.append(key + ':' +value );
            alert(key);
        }
        ));
        container.append('<br/></br>');
    });
});

</script>
```

now iam adding the json file below

```
{"data":[{"title":"Somerset 436/10  v Surrey 69/1 *","description":"Somerset 436/10  v Surrey 69/1 *","unique_id":"1068564"},{"title":"Zimbabwe A v South Africa Emerging Players 298/4 *","description":"Zimbabwe A v South Africa Emerging Players 298/4 *","unique_id":"1114833"},{"title":"Trinbago Knight Riders 147/10  v Jamaica Tallawahs 148/6 *","description":"Trinbago Knight Riders 147/10  v Jamaica Tallawahs 148/6 *","unique_id":"1094678"},{"title":"Band-e-Amir Region 92/2 * v Speen Ghar Region","description":"Band-e-Amir Region 92/2 * v Speen Ghar Region","unique_id":"1115759"},{"title":"Mis Ainak Region v Amo Region 91/2 *","description":"Mis Ainak Region v Amo Region 91/2 *","unique_id":"1115760"},{"title":"Southern Vipers v Western Storm","description":"Southern Vipers v Western Storm","unique_id":"1093476"},{"title":"Lyca Kovai Kings v Madurai Super Giant","description":"Lyca Kovai Kings v Madurai Super Giant","unique_id":"1107276"},{"title":"Middlesex v Sussex","description":"Middlesex v Sussex","unique_id":"1068394"},{"title":"Hampshire v Glamorgan","description":"Hampshire v Glamorgan","unique_id":"1068393"},{"title":"St Lucia Stars v Barbados Tridents","description":"St Lucia Stars v Barbados Tridents","unique_id":"1094679"}],"cache":false,"v":"1","ttl":342,"provider":{"source":"Various","url":"https://cricapi.com/","pubDate":"2017-08-10T07:00:36.898Z"},"creditsLeft":249}
```

Comment: Have you error ? What do you get if you open http://cricapi.com/api/cricket/?apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  on your browser?

Comment: yes i have json file in that link file but i have hidden apikey for security reason ,

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is the `this` you put on the `each`. It should be data or data.data.  There is also some issue with closing ) and }. Here is an exemple that is ok.

```js
function myFunc(){
  var container=document.getElementById("cont");
  alert(container);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://cricapi.com/api/cricket/?apikey=TESTKEY0273', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
     $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
      container.append(key + ':' +value.description +" <br />\n");
     });
    }
  });
             
   }
    
$(document).ready(myFunc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: I've write a snippet that is ok.